# How to make fixed button flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with fixed button inside scroll view , I made a column with SingleChildScrollView and two button, but the problem is that the screen do not scroll. I tried the bottom Navigation bar but it has the same problem. How I can fix this?

my code :

```
 Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 200,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text("200");
                },
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text("bargougui");
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.grey[300],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Contacter',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Acheter',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[screen I want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ahDS.png)

any help will be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stack` widget,

```dart
Stack(
 children:[
  SingleChildScrollView(),
  Positioned(
   bottom:0,
   left:15,
   right:15,
   child:Row(children :[Button1(),Button2()],
   ,)
 ]
```

Try tweaking the numbers to fit your case.

Comment: hi, i do this but when i add bottom :0 , left:15, the two button was hidden ?

Comment: Make your `Column` a `Stack` widget, remove `Expanded` from the `SingleChildScrollView` and add `Expanded` to your `ListView.builder`s. Then wrap your `Row` with the `Positioned` widget and give it the position you want.